# Chamar procedure PL/SQL com coleção de objetos

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, pl-sql

Considere os seguintes tipos:

```
CREATE TYPE meu_tipo AS OBJECT (
  meu_id       NUMBER(6),
  meu_nome     VARCHAR2(200)
);

CREATE TYPE meu_tipo_tabela AS TABLE OF meu_tipo;
```

E o seguinte pacote:

```
create or replace package pkg_test
is
    procedure meu_procedure(tabela in meu_tipo_tabela);
end;
```

Do lado do PL/SQL poderíamos chamar esse *procedure* da seguinte maneira:

```
declare
    var_minha_tabela meu_tipo_tabela := meu_tipo_tabela(
        meu_tipo(1,'John'),
        meu_tipo(2,'Doe'),
        meu_tipo(3,'Snow'));
begin
    pkg_test.meu_procedure(var_minha_tabela);
end;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/39eaa/1)

---

Minha dúvida é: Como faço essa mesma chamada com Java e JDBC?

```
public void chamarProcedure(List<MeuTipo> minhaLista) {
    final String chamada = "{call PKG_TEST.MEU_PROCEDURE(?)}";
    try (Connection connection = getDataSource().getConnection();
         CallableStatement callableSt = connection.prepareCall(chamada)) {
         // ??? - Código para criar um ARRAY, STRUCT ou algo assim a partir da lista.
         callableSt.setArray(1, ???);
         callableSt.executeUpdate();   
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error("Erro ao chamar procedure", e);
        // Lançamento de exceção não checada
    }
}
```

Em especial acredito que devo, de alguma maneira, criar um `oracle.sql.ARRAY` de `meu_tipo_tabela`, porém, não consegui encontrar nenhum exemplo de como fazer isso (chamada com `ARRAY` de objetos complexos).

Comment: Encontrei [esse exemplo](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-passing-array-to-oracle-stored-procedure/) com um array de primitivos. A mesma estratégia não funcionou para meu array de tipo complexos.

Comment: Na linha final String chamada = "{call PKG_TEST.MEU_PRODECURE(?)}"; não tentou trocar o bing pela passagem direta ? algo como final String chamada = "{call PKG_TEST.MEU_PRODECURE(1,'John')}";  ?

Comment: Infelizmente isso não funciona (não são parâmetros simples, é uma coleção de objetos complexos conforme a chamada PL/SQL de exemplo).

Comment: Entendo , com um CAST talvez String chamada = "{call PKG_TEST.MEU_PRODECURE( cast(1,'John') as meu_tipo)}"; mas estas soluções que falo me soam como "gambiarra" deve ter uma forma correta ainda mais em java

Comment: Qual é o erro que ocorre ao tentar transformar o exemplo com coleção de primitivos numa coleção de objetos complexos? Você já viu a documentação do driver JDBC da Oracle? O link para a versão 10g é este:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/toc.htm
Lá tem exemplos de como usar STRUCT e ARRAY, embora também não tenha encontrado ainda um exemplo combinando os dois.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postando a solução para outros usuários que eventualmente encontrem o mesmo problema.

O [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42748/chamar-procedure-pl-sql-com-cole%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-objetos#comment88511_42748) do [marcus](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2452/marcus) me ajudou a matar a charada.

Na verdade o que precisamos construir é um `ARRAY` de `STRUCTS`. Cada uma dessas estruturas requer um `TypeDescriptor` e um array de atributos (no caso de `STRUCT` podemos também usar um `Map` de atributos; veja [os construtores de `STRUCT`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/STRUCT.html)). 
Como a demonstração da solução é um tanto quanto complexa criei um [repositório no GitHub](https://github.com/aaccioly/TesteOracleTypes).

Segue uma breve descrição da técnica utilizada:

1. A chamada do *procedure* segue o *template* da pergunta. O parâmetro de entrada é do tipo proprietário `oracle.sql.ARRAY`:

   ```
   public void chamarProcedure(List<MeuTipo> minhaLista) {
       final String chamada = "{call PKG_TEST.MEU_PROCEDURE(?)}";
       try (Connection connection = getConnection();
            CallableStatement callableSt = connection.prepareCall(chamada)) {

           final ARRAY minhaTabela = toArray(minhaLista, connection);
           callableSt.setArray(1, minhaTabela);
           callableSt.executeUpdate();
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```
2. O método `toArray` cria um array to tipo `STRUCT[]` a partir dos elementos da lista. O `STRUCT[]` é então embrulhado com um `oracle.sql.ARRAY`. Para tanto também são criados os descritores para `MEU_TIPO` e `MEU_TIPO_TABELA`:

   ```
   private ARRAY toArray(List<MeuTipo> minhaLista, Connection connection) 
           throws SQLException {
       final STRUCT[] structArray = new STRUCT[minhaLista.size()];
       final ListIterator<MeuTipo> iterator = minhaLista.listIterator();
       final StructDescriptor structDescriptor = StructDescriptor
               .createDescriptor("MEU_TIPO", connection);
       while (iterator.hasNext()) {
           structArray[iterator.nextIndex()] = 
                  toStruct(iterator.next(), structDescriptor, connection);
       }
       final ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor
               .createDescriptor("MEU_TIPO_TABELA", connection);

       return new ARRAY(arrayDescriptor, connection, structArray);
   }
   ```
3. Finalmente o método `toStruct` cria um `Object[]` a partir de um item to tipo `MeuTipo`. Como no passo 2 o `Object[]` é embrulhado com um `oracle.sql.STRUCT`. Os valores no `Object[]` devem obedecer a ordem dos atributos do objeto declarado do lado do Oracle:

   ```
   private STRUCT toStruct(MeuTipo meuTipo, StructDescriptor structDescriptor, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
       final Object[] attributes = new Object[]{meuTipo.getMeuId(), meuTipo.getMeuNome()};
       return new STRUCT(structDescriptor, connection, attributes);
   }
   ```

---

**Referência:** [SOen - How to call oracle stored procedure which include user-defined type in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3627613/664577)